# Send tcp commands through a new form

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient, networkstream

I am able to open a TcpClient connection in C#, open a network stream, and send commands successfully. I was able to login with a username and password. Then sent some commands to control the system and it works fine.

How can I send commands to that stream I already opened if I create a new form?

I want to open a new form and have the user push buttons that will send commands through the stream I already opened. I'm not exactly sure how to do this because I will run into errors if I try to open the same stream again.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you can use this link : http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/

Comment: Thanks John and thanks Arash for the good info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a separate class that encapsulates the network-related behaviour.  Your TcpClient will be instantiated in that class.  Then you can either pass a reference to that class to new forms in their constructor, or you can use the [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern.

Note that keeping unrelated behaviour (such as GUI and networking) separate is a [Good Idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: I did make a telnet class from where I establish the TcpClient connection and network stream. I just create an instance of this class from a main form. Then I open another form and send data from it. I think I might have the right direction but missing one step. Thanks for the info

Comment: Pass a reference to your telnet class around to other forms